# Carousel stops sliding after short time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Every second this carousel should automatically slide to the next `div` element and append the current one to the end of the caroussel. This works, however after a very short time this does not work anymore and I have no idea why. Does anyone have suggestions?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $(".element")
    .eq(0)
    .css({
      "margin-left": "-245px"
    })
    .delay(3000)
    .queue(function(next) {
      $(this).appendTo(".wrapper").css({
        "margin-left": "10px"
      });
    });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.mgcont {
  margin: 5% auto;
  width: 970px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 960px;
}

.element {
  width: 240px;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: margin-left 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mgcont">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">1</div>
    <div class="element">2</div>
    <div class="element">3</div>
    <div class="element">4</div>
    <div class="element">5</div>
    <div class="element">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error do you get in the console? What browser? When does it stop working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `next`. See https://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback.

> Note that when adding a function with `.queue()`, we should ensure that `.dequeue()` is eventually called so that the next function in line executes.
>
> **As of jQuery 1.4**, the function that's called is passed another function as the first argument. When called, this automatically dequeues the next item and keeps the queue moving.

```
.queue(function(next) {
  $(this).appendTo(".wrapper").css({
    "margin-left": "10px"
  });
  next();
});
```

That being said, I have found two additional problems.

The first problem is related to the HTML code. I've noted that you move the element 255 (10 + 245) pixels to the left instead of 250 (10 + 240). I guess that you are trying to get rid of this little glitch at the end of each animation. Good news, there is a clean way to remove it completely. It comes from invisible text nodes related to the white spaces inserted between the elements. Remove the white spaces in the source code and the text nodes will disappear :

```
<div class="wrapper"
  ><div class="element">1</div
  ><div class="element">2</div
  ><div class="element">3</div
  ><div class="element">4</div
  ><div class="element">5</div
  ><div class="element">6</div
></div>
```

The second problem is related to the JS code. An element needs 3 seconds to reach its final position, but you repeat the instructions every second. Hence, the last function is queued at least 3 times for each element, and the queue is likely to grow more and more, slowing down your web browser if not crashing it. To avoid this tragedy, you should trigger the next animation when the current one has completed. This can be done like so :

```
setTimeout(slide, 1000);

function slide () {
  $(".element")
    .eq(0)
    ...
    .queue(function(next) {
      ...
      setTimeout(slide, 1000);
    });
}
```

With these two problems fixed, the resulting program is a lot better, but I have one last comment. It's weird to wait 3 seconds in JS to let the CSS transition complete, this is not very accurate. I think it's better not to mix CSS transition and JS animations, rather do it entirely in JS.

That's it :-) As a summary, have a look at the demo below.

```js
setTimeout(slide, 1000);

function slide () {
  $(".element")
    .eq(0)
    .css("margin-left", "-40px")
    .delay(3000)
    .queue(function(next) {
      $(this).appendTo(".wrapper").css({
        "margin-left": "10px"
      });
      next();
      setTimeout(slide, 1000);
    });
}
```

```css
.mgcont {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.element {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: margin-left 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mgcont">
  <div class="wrapper"
    ><div class="element">1</div
    ><div class="element">2</div
    ><div class="element">3</div
    ><div class="element">4</div
    ><div class="element">5</div
    ><div class="element">6</div
  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that you rely on the `.appendTo()` behavior doing a remove from previous location and append to the next. Instead, jQuery detects that the DOM node did not change and optimizes out the removal.

To fix change

```
$(this).appendTo(".wrapper")
```

To

```
$(this).remove().appendTo(".wrapper")
```